# Insert Firestore data into pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Thread is solved after I got help from the comments.

I saw another thread about this, but it didn't helped me after hours of tries. So I'd no choice of creating a new thread. (Sorry for that)

In the beginning of the class I've this:

```
//Firestore connection
let db = Firestore.firestore()

//Create an array of items to insert into pickerview
var dogsArray: [String] = []
```

Inside the ViewDidLoad I've Delegate and Datasource for the pickerview.

```
    override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getDogs()


    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self

}
```

And a little bit down, I got this code:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        return dogsArray[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return dogsArray.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        labeltest.text = dogsArray[row]
    }

    func getDogs()
{
    db.collection("Dogs").getDocuments
        { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: err))");
            }
            else
            {
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents
                {
          let document = QuerySnapshot!.documents.first
                    let data = document!.data()
                    data.forEach { (item) in
                        if let dogOneData = data["Dog1"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogOneData)
                        }

                        if let dogTwoData = data["Dog2"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogTwoData)
                        }

                        if let dogThreeData = data["Dog3"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogThreeData)
                        }

                }
                    self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
    }
}
```

> Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to closure result type
>   'String?' on the return (dogElement.value as? [String:
>   Any])?.values.first

So I'm trying to select data from Firestore and insert it into a pickerview. But the data I want to select is data I entered when registered on the application. So everyone's is unique. 
(Ex. If you register on the app, your dog names is different from mine.)

So I'm trying to select data from a specific user. But I've no idea how to do. And the result is blank at the moment, I cannot see any data at all in the pickerview. So, I'd love to get some help on this! You would make my Friday be a good one. :)

Database structure: [image: structure]

---

RESULT AFTER SOLVED:

```
//Function getDogs()
func getDogs()
{
    //Authentication
    let authentication = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    //Choosing collection
    db.collection("users").document(authentication!).collection("Dogs").getDocuments()
        { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
            if err != nil
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: err))");
            }
            else
            {
                //For-loop
                for _ in QuerySnapshot!.documents
                {
                    self.dogsArray.removeAll()
                    let document = QuerySnapshot!.documents.first
                    let data = document!.data()
                    data.forEach { (item) in
                        if let dogOneData = data["Dog1"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogOneData)
                        }

                        if let dogTwoData = data["Dog2"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogTwoData)
                        }

                        if let dogThreeData = data["Dog3"] as? String {
                            self.dogsArray.append(dogThreeData)
                        }

                }
                    self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
```

Comment: You're saying the error occurs on the line `return (dogElement.value as? [String: Any])?.values.first` however, that line doesn't appear in your question.

Comment: @Jay I have fixed that issue already. (If you check the accepted one) But still stuck on the firebase rules.

Comment: Understood - I was pointing that out for future readers. I really think you're headed in the wrong direction with your structure, based on your prior two questions. I am all about denormalizing data but it appears to be unneeded in this case. That's IMO however, and it may work for your use case.

Comment: So, you do know how I can do this? I created two new questions because of: 

1.) This is already solved, and the other question isn't really about this. It's about the database structure to insert the correct values.

2.) I've no idea how to bump the thread, and since I really need this. I don't know what else I can do...

Comment: From what I am seeing in prior and this question, it's unclear *why* you have three separate categories; *Dogs, Person, UserInfo* and the relationship is also unclear. If a user can have several Person objects and several Dogs, why are they in a totally separate category? If they are related to only one user, put them within the user. So a typical use case would be a node like */users*. A child of that would be the user id */users/uid_0*. Then related child node such as */fav_food* and perhaps */shoe_size* etc which eliminates the userInfo node. Then a child categories /dogs and /persons

Comment: @Jay I solved my issue, finally. one week later and it's all done. Thanks for your help thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call getData on a delegate function and because it is unsynchronized they are not being load before the rest of the delegate functions get called.

You should first call the `getData()` function and then reload the PickerviewDataSource

For example on `viewDidAppear()` function call the

`getDogs()`

and add inside the `getDogs()` function, after the loop

```
    dogsArray.removeAll()
    let document = QuerySnapshot!.documents.first
        let data = document.data()
    data.forEach { (item) in
        if let dogOneData = item["Dog1"] as? String {
            dogsArray.append(dogOneData)
        }

        if let dogTwoData = item["Dog2"] as? String {
            dogsArray.append(dogTwoData)
        }

        if let dogThreeData = item["Dog3"] as? String {
            dogsArray.append(dogThreeData)
        }
    }

self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188899/discussion-between-putte-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't call `getDogs` in `titleForRow`call it in `viewDidLoad`

Secondly, you need to call reload after the loop.

```
func getDogs()
    {
        db.collection("Dogs").getDocuments
            { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
                if err != nil
                {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: err))");
                }
                else
                {
                    for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents
                    {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let dogs = data["Dogs"] as? String ?? ""

                        self.dogsArray.append(dogs)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```